# Help installing rtl88x2bu drivers

Tags: drivers

I've just setup a new install of Linux mint and cannot connect to WiFi.

I'm living in university accommodation and the ethernet only seems to connect to devices / services on the university network, so I'm stuck using WiFi.

I have a pair of WiFi dongles (with realtek 8812bu and 8811 chipsets respectively) neither of which are recognised by my Linux mint install so I'm trying to install drivers for them.

I've cloned [this repository](https://github.com/fastoe/RTL8812BU) - which should contain drivers for the 8812BU chipset - onto a usb stick and I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.fastoe.com/blog/install-rtl8812bu-usb-wifi-dongle-on-linux) which outlines using dkms to install these drivers.

`dkms add ...` works, but `dkms build ...` fails with the message:

```
make -j16 KERNELRELEASE=5.4.0-91-generic KVER=5.4.0-91-generic src=/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1...
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-91-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.6.1/build/make.log for more informatio.
```

I consult that log and find:

```
DKMS make.log ...
Sat 14 May ...
Makefile:2204 /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1/hal/phydm.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1/hal/phydm.mk'. Stop.
```

Bare in mind, I have absoloutely no internet connection on the Linux Mint install.

Comment: Check if you are building the right source for your running kernel. There are many branches, you might have to tweak the tutorial a bit.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise drivers were kernel version specific (seems obvious now that I'm saying it)